# calculate value of Checked boxes using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html code:
I want to calculate the price associated with each checked box and display it in a text area after i click order (button). Pls help!

```
<div>

    <form>
    <fieldset > <legend>Resturant Menu:</legend>

      <input type="checkbox" id = "menu" value="300">   
        <label> Chicken-------------------------- 300 AFN</label> <br>
      <input type="checkbox" id = "menu" value="200"> 
        <label> Chicken Baryani --------------- 200 AFN</label> <br>
      <input type="checkbox" id = "menu"    value="250">
        <label> Chicken Kabab -----------------  250 AFN</label> <br>
      <input type="checkbox" id = "menu"   value="100">
        <label> Juice -----------------------------  100 AFN</label> <br>
      <input type="submit" id = "submit_btn" onclick = "calculate()">


    </fieldset>

</form>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try yourself?

Comment: Please first try to write a solution in JS and then let us help you debug it if you still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually not how it works on StackOverflow, you have to try fixing it yourself. However, I'm bored so here is a solution with HTML + Javascript.

It is bad practice to declare multiple ids with the same name, use classes instead. I changed your code a little bit. You said you want to display the code in another field, so using a form for this is not necessary.

```js
var menuItems = document.getElementsByClassName('menuItem');
var orderButton = document.getElementById('order_btn');
var totalArea = document.getElementById('total');
var afn = 0;

orderButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
    if (menuItems[i].checked) {
      afn += +menuItems[i].value;
    }
  }
  totalArea.innerHTML = "Total: " + afn + " AFN";
  afn = 0;
});
```

```html
<div>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Resturant Menu:</legend>

    <input type="checkbox" class="menuItem" value="300">
    <label>Chicken-------------------------- 300 AFN</label>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="menuItem" value="200">
    <label>Chicken Baryani --------------- 200 AFN</label>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="menuItem" value="250">
    <label>Chicken Kabab ----------------- 250 AFN</label>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="menuItem" value="100">
    <label>Juice ----------------------------- 100 AFN</label>
    <br>
    <button id="order_btn">Order</button>
  </fieldset>
  <p id="total">Total: 0 AFN</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function calculate(){
            var allMenuItem = $('#menuItem input[type=checkbox]');
            var totalPrice = 0;
            $.each(allMenuItem, function(key, element){
                if($(this).is(":checked")){
                    totalPrice += parseFloat($(this).val());
                }
            });

            alert("You order price is: "+ totalPrice + " Rs");
        }
    </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
        <fieldset > <legend>Resturant Menu:</legend>
            <div id="menuItem">
            <input type="checkbox" id = "menu" value="300">
            <label> Chicken-------------------------- 300 AFN</label> <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id = "menu" value="200">
            <label> Chicken Baryani --------------- 200 AFN</label> <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id = "menu"    value="250">
            <label> Chicken Kabab -----------------  250 AFN</label> <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id = "menu"   value="100">
            <label> Juice -----------------------------  100 AFN</label> <br>
            <input type="button" value="Order" id = "submit_btn" onclick = "calculate()">
            </div>
        </fieldset>

    </form>
```